# Output as a specific Dict and a List of Dict

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse some commands-like string/file content into a Dict output and I learned about pyparsing.

So let's say I have the following input:

```
str = "p1 start a, {alias = b, for : 30}; c, d stop e"
```

and to parse it, I'm using this:

```
import pyparsing as pp



grammar = pp.Forward()

SEP = pp.one_of(", ;")
EQ = pp.Suppress(pp.one_of(': ='))
LBRACE, RBRACE = map(pp.Suppress,"{}")
CMD_KEYWORD = (pp.CaselessKeyword("start") | pp.CaselessKeyword("stop") | pp.CaselessKeyword("resume"))
platform = pp.one_of("p1 p2 p3")("platform")
alias = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
prop = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
value = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
prop_value = pp.Dict(pp.Group(prop + EQ + value))
task_config = LBRACE + pp.delimitedList(prop_value, delim = SEP) + RBRACE
command = CMD_KEYWORD + pp.Group(pp.delimitedList(task_config | alias, delim = SEP))("tasks")
expr = platform + command[1, ...]("commands")

grammar <<= expr

res = grammar.parse_string(str)

print(res.as_dict())

print(res.as_list())
```

which results in the following Dict and List

```
{'platform': 'p1', 'tasks': ['e'], 'commands': ['start', {'alias': 'b', 'for': '30'}, 'stop', ['e']]}
['p1', 'start', ['a', ['alias', 'b'], ['for', '30'], 'c', 'd'], 'stop', ['e']]
```

While what I was(still) trying to achieve, is to get the output in a specific Dict format, something like this:

```
{
 [
  {
   'platform': 'p1',
   'commands': [
                {'cmd': 'start', 'tasks': [{'alias': 'a'}, {'alias': 'b', 'for': '30'}, {'alias': 'c'}, {'alias': 'd'}]},
                {'cmd': 'stop', 'tasks': [{'alias': 'e'}]}
               ],

  }       
 ]
}
```

**Edit:**

After some trial and errors I managed to (almost) achieve what I'm aiming for after making some changes to my parser grammar:

```
import pyparsing as pp

def set_alias(t):
    return {"alias": t[0]}

grammar = pp.Forward()

SEP = pp.one_of(", ;")
EQ = pp.Suppress(pp.one_of(': ='))
LBRACE, RBRACE = map(pp.Suppress,"{}")
OPT_SEP = pp.Suppress(pp.Opt(SEP))
CMD_KEYWORD = (pp.CaselessKeyword("start") | pp.CaselessKeyword("stop") | pp.CaselessKeyword("resume"))("cmd")
platform = pp.one_of("p1 p2 p3")("platform")
alias = ~(CMD_KEYWORD | platform) + pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
prop = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
value = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
prop_value = pp.Dict(pp.Group(prop + EQ + value))
task_config = LBRACE + pp.Group(pp.delimitedList(prop_value, delim = SEP)) + RBRACE
command = pp.Group(CMD_KEYWORD + pp.Group(pp.OneOrMore((task_config | alias.set_parse_action(set_alias)) + OPT_SEP))("tasks"))
expr = platform + command[1, ...]("commands")

grammar <<= pp.OneOrMore(expr + OPT_SEP)

print(res.as_dict())

print(res.as_list())
```

But when I'm testing it with the following input:

```
p1 start a, {alias = b, for : 30}; c, d stop e p2 resume f
```

I get:

```
{'platform': 'p2', 'commands': [{'cmd': 'resume', 'tasks': [{'alias': 'f'}]}]}

['p1', ['start', [{'alias': 'a'}, [['alias', 'b'], ['for', '30']], {'alias': 'c'}, {'alias': 'd'}]], ['stop', [{'alias': 'e'}]], 'p2', ['resume', [{'alias': 'f'}]]]
```

And as you can see the **res.as_list()** returns all the expected tokens, but the **res.as_dict()** only returns the **'platform': 'p2'** part missing the **'platfrom': 'p1'** one and I can't figure out the reason for it.

**Edit2:**

I've solved it for now, by changing the last part to:

```
expr = pp.Dict(pp.Group(platform + command[1, ...]("commands")))
    
grammar <<= pp.OneOrMore(expr + OPT_SEP)
```

and I got the following Dict as output:

```
{'p1': {'platform': 'p1', 'commands': [{'cmd': 'start', 'tasks': [{'alias': 'a'}, {'alias': 'b', 'for': '30'}, {'alias': 'c'}, {'alias': 'd'}]}, {'cmd': 'stop', 'tasks': [{'alias': 'e'}]}]},


'p2': {'platform': 'p2', 'commands': [{'cmd': 'resume', 'tasks': [{'alias': 'f'}]}]}}


[['p1', ['start', [{'alias': 'a'}, [['alias', 'b'], ['for', '30']], {'alias': 'c'}, {'alias': 'd'}]], ['stop', [{'alias': 'e'}]]], ['p2', ['resume', [{'alias': 'f'}]]]]
```

Maybe I'll answer my own question and mark it as solved later, because I realised that I need to update my parser to retrun a **List** of **Dictionaries** instead of just a large Dict because the order of processing the parser output is very important.

Comment: The key in a dict (the part in front of the colon) must be unique. You cannot have a dict that contains both 'platform': 'p1' and 'platform' : 'p2' as this would mean that you have the same key twice. If you try to set that key again its value gets overwritten.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed that, which made me realise that what I really need is an output as a List of Dicts and not just a Dict, because the order of processing this output later on is very important.

Comment: Why are some variables capitalized? Are they supposed to be constants?

Comment: @Elerium115 Yes, you got it right

Comment: as_dict() will only show expressions that have results names. Try using `print(res.dump())`.  Or run your tests using `grammar.run_tests`, which uses dump() to give the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'll answer my own question tested on the following input string:

> p1 start a, {alias = b, for : 30}; c, d stop e; p2 resume f p3 start
> {name = g, at = 5}

```
import pyparsing as pp

def set_alias(t):
    return {"alias": t[0]}

def set_expr(t):
    for expre in t.as_dict().values():
        result.append(expre)

str = "p1 start a, {alias = b, for : 30}; c, d stop e; p2 resume f p3 start {name = g, at = 5}"


# result will represent the output as a List of Dictionaries
result = []

grammar = pp.Forward()

SEP = pp.one_of(", ;")
EQ = pp.Suppress(pp.one_of(': ='))
LBRACE, RBRACE = map(pp.Suppress,"{}")
OPT_SEP = pp.Suppress(pp.Opt(SEP))
CMD_KEYWORD = (pp.CaselessKeyword("start") | pp.CaselessKeyword("stop") | pp.CaselessKeyword("resume"))("cmd")
platform = pp.one_of("p1 p2 p3")("platform")
alias = ~(CMD_KEYWORD | platform) + pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
prop = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
value = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
prop_value = pp.Dict(pp.Group(prop + EQ + value))
task_config = LBRACE + pp.Group(pp.delimitedList(prop_value, delim = SEP)) + RBRACE
command = pp.Group(CMD_KEYWORD + pp.Group(pp.OneOrMore((task_config | alias.set_parse_action(set_alias)) + OPT_SEP))("tasks"))
expr = pp.Dict(pp.Group(platform + command[1, ...]("commands"))).setParseAction(set_expr)

grammar <<= pp.OneOrMore(expr + OPT_SEP)

print('\nDict = ', res.as_dict())

print('\n List of Dict = ', result)

print('\nList of Tokens =', res.as_list())
```

which restults in :

```
Dict =  {'p1': {'platform': 'p1', 'commands': [{'cmd': 'start', 'tasks': [{'alias': 'a'}, {'alias': 'b', 'for': '30'}, {'alias': 'c'}, {'alias': 'd'}]}, {'cmd': 'stop', 'tasks': [{'alias': 'e'}]}]}, 'p2': {'platform': 'p2', 'commands': [{'cmd': 'resume', 'tasks': [{'alias': 'f'}]}]}, 'p3': {'platform': 'p3', 'commands': [{'cmd': 'start', 'tasks': [{'name': 'g', 'at': '5'}]}]}}


List of Dict =  [{'platform': 'p1', 'commands': [{'cmd': 'start', 'tasks': [{'alias': 'a'}, {'alias': 'b', 'for': '30'}, {'alias': 'c'}, {'alias': 
'd'}]}, {'cmd': 'stop', 'tasks': [{'alias': 'e'}]}]}, {'platform': 'p2', 'commands': [{'cmd': 'resume', 'tasks': [{'alias': 'f'}]}]}, {'platform': 'p3', 'commands': [{'cmd': 'start', 'tasks': [{'name': 'g', 'at': '5'}]}]}]


List of Tokens = [['p1', ['start', [{'alias': 'a'}, [['alias', 'b'], ['for', '30']], {'alias': 'c'}, {'alias': 'd'}]], ['stop', [{'alias': 'e'}]]], ['p2', ['resume', [{'alias': 'f'}]]], ['p3', ['start', [[['name', 'g'], ['at', '5']]]]]]
```